# Excel VBA Add Spaces to Cells

Tags: vba, email, excel, automation

I have 10 columns of data with a varying number of rows which is emailed as an unformatted range. I want to be able to right pad the cells in each column with spaces so the unformatted range copies over as evenly spaced. The reason the range is unformatted is I am using LotusNotes and I don't have the integration options like I have with Outlook. Is there anyway without adding columns that I can pad the cells with a space character so the range looks good in an email?

EDIT: So this allows me to type in an email via an input box and select a range. It will create the email and send but it dosen't preserve the cell formatting (i.e spacing) Can this be done? I have tried using the MIME entities to use HTML however I'm not sure how I'd copy the range into the HTML body

Updated Code:

```
Sub Lotus_Email()

Dim noSession As Object, noDatabase As Object, noDocument As Object
Dim vaRecipient As String
Dim rnBody As Range
Dim Data As DataObject

Const stSubject As String = "EMAIL SUBJECT"
Const stMsg As String = "Please review the following Purchase Orders and advise."
Const stPrompt As String = "Please select the range:"

'This is one technique to send an e-mail to many recipients but for larger
'number of recipients it's more convenient to read the recipient-list from
'a range in the workbook.
vaRecipient = InputBox("Please enter an e-mail address", "E-Mail Address Entry")

On Error Resume Next
Set rnBody = Application.InputBox(Prompt:=stPrompt, _
     Default:=Selection.Address, Type:=8)


'The user canceled the operation.
If rnBody Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

On Error GoTo 0

'Instantiate Lotus Notes COM's objects.
Set noSession = CreateObject("Notes.NotesSession")
Set noDatabase = noSession.GETDATABASE("", "")

'Make sure Lotus Notes is open and available.
If noDatabase.IsOpen = False Then noDatabase.OPENMAIL

'Create the document for the e-mail.
Set noDocument = noDatabase.CreateDocument

'Copy the selected range into memory.
rnBody.Copy

Set rtItem = noDocument.CreateRichTextItem("Body")
With rtItem
.appendtext ("LINE 1")
.addnewline (2)
.appendtext ("LINE 2")
.addnewline (2)
.addnewline (1)
.appendtext ("Please review and respond to the email noted above")
.appendtext ("TEST")
rnBody.PasteSpecial
End With

'Add data to the mainproperties of the e-mail's document.
With noDocument
   .Form = "Memo"
   .SendTo = vaRecipient
   .Subject = stSubject
   'Retrieve the data from the clipboard.
   ' NON-HTML BODY OFF
   ' .Body = stMsg & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & Data.GetText
   .SaveMessageOnSend = True
End With


'Send the e-mail.
With noDocument
   .PostedDate = Now()
   .Send 0, vaRecipient
End With

'Release objects from memory.
Set noDocument = Nothing
Set noDatabase = Nothing
Set noSession = Nothing


'Activate Excel for the user.
AppActivate "Microsoft Excel"

'Empty the clipboard.
Application.CutCopyMode = False

MsgBox "The e-mail has successfully been created and distributed.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you emailing in HTML format?  If so, you can add the spacing to the cell border spacing.

Comment: I don't believe so. I have a prompt box which selects a cell range (Application.InputBox) and then that becomes the .Body of the email. Outlook has the option of formatting via HTML but it dosen't appear the LotusNotes has this

Comment: Lotus Notes definitely can send HTML emails.  Also, you can integrate Microsoft Office into Lotus Notes using OLE.  Refer to http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/library/notes-ole/

Answer (score 0):

UNTESTED. Maybe something like this?:

```
=A1&REPT(" ",25-LEN(A1))
```

Comment: This does work! however the reason I'm trying to avoid formulas is the cells autoupdate with new information often which would overwrite my formulas :(

Answer (score 0):

So after using LotusNotes MIME I could import Rich Text, however it wouldn't preserve column width and excel formatting. I created a temp workbook with my range selection and attached it as an attachment. This seems to be the way to handle this with LotusNotes.